# How to find files older than x days on Windows using Advanced Query Syntax (AQS)?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, search

You can find files older than this week using

```
datemodified:< this week
```

but

```
datemodified:< 7 days
```

does not seem to work.

Answer (score 10):

#### How to find files older than x days on Windows

```
datemodified:< 7 days
```

> doesn't seem to work.

When referring to relative date 'values' using the `<` or `>` the value cannot be any of the keyword values related to dates (listed below). It must be a value using the format `dd/mm/yy` (or whatever format is specified in the "Region and Language" settings.

To find files older than `x` days, use the following:

```
datemodified:< dd/mm/yy
```

where `dd/mm/yy` is `x` days before the current (today's) date.

Notes:

- When entering dates use the date format which matches the "Control Panel" > "Region and Language" settings.
- There is one exception to this, years should always be entered as 4 digits.

---

#### Searching using filters

Here are examples of the supported date related filters

```
Criteria                                Syntax/Example
Date created (exact date)               datecreated:8/2/2012
Date created (range)                    datecreated:8/2/2012..8/3/2012
Date created (before)                   datecreated:<8/2/2012
Date created (after)                    datecreated:>8/2/2012
Date created prior to the current year  datecreated:a long time ago
Date created within the current year    datecreated:earlier this year
Date created within the current month   datecreated:earlier this month
Date created within the current week    datecreated:earlier this week
Date created yesterday                  datecreated:yesterday
Date created today                      datecreated:today
Date modified (exact date)              datemodified:8/2/2012
Date modified (range)                   datemodified:8/2/2012..8/3/2012
Date modified (before)                  datemodified:<8/2/2012
Date modified (after)                   datemodified:>8/2/2012
Date modified prior to the current year datemodified:a long time ago
Date modified within the current year   datemodified:earlier this year
Date modified within the current month  datemodified:earlier this month
Date modified within the current week   datemodified:earlier this week
Date modified yesterday                 datemodified:yesterday
Date modified today                     datemodified:today
```

Source [Windows 7 search explained](http://mfctips.com/2012/08/02/windows-7-search-explained/)

---

#### Keyword values related to dates

The following keywords can be user when referring to dates.

> Relative dates: Today, tomorrow, yesterday
>
> Multi-word relative dates: week, next month, last week, past month, or
>   coming year.
>
> The values can also be entered contracted, as follows: thisweek,
>   nextmonth, lastweek, pastmonth, comingyear.
>
> Days: Sunday, Monday ... Saturday
>
> Months: January, February ... December

Source [Using Advanced Query Syntax To Find Files in Windows 7](http://blogs.technet.com/b/alanlemarquand/archive/2010/08/13/using_2d00_advanced_2d00_query_2d00_syntax_2d00_to_2d00_find_2d00_files_2d00_in_2d00_windows_2d00_7.aspx)

---

#### Further reading

- [Windows 7 search explained](http://mfctips.com/2012/08/02/windows-7-search-explained/)
- [Using Advanced Query Syntax To Find Files in Windows 7](http://blogs.technet.com/b/alanlemarquand/archive/2010/08/13/using_2d00_advanced_2d00_query_2d00_syntax_2d00_to_2d00_find_2d00_files_2d00_in_2d00_windows_2d00_7.aspx)